# How do i completly lock a file on windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I am currently working on a project that includes the complete lock of some files on windows, by complete lock i mean that the file cannot be accessed by another process nor by the system (copy, paste, delete). the Lockfile function was the closest i got to a solution but, i am not sure if the unlockfile function can override and grant access to a different process. so my question is: does Lockfile really lock hermetically the file and can it be overridden?

Comment: Just open the file for exclusive access (no sharing rights granted to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third parameter of CreateFile specifies sharing options, by specifying no flags (0) for this param, you get a lock on the file.

```
HANDLE hFile = 
   CreateFile(L"filename.txt", 
              GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
              0,     // by specifying 0, you get exclusive access
              NULL,
              OPEN_EXISTING,
              FILE_FLAG_NORMAL, 
              NULL);

if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // lock obtained
}
else
{
   // file not exist or file is being used by something else
}
```

Closing the returned file handle releases the lock. (Also, exiting the process will release the lock).

```
CloseHandle(hFile);
hFile = NULL;
```